# How to get Credit Card Balance?

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, credit-card, authorize.net

Is there ability to get in some way Balance on CreditCard ?

API of Authorize.net or Paypal were examined on this subject and no results.
In real life any cash terminal can show to you balance on your credit card. That is why I assume there is some way to get this balance in web through some payment gateway.

Thanks in advance for answers!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've dealt with many credit card processing APIs and unless it is an API for a gateway solution, they generally do not have methods to do much in the way of querying for information.  You might see some capability (again, in a gateway API but not in a lower-level processor's API) to load details of the original transaction, but not much else.

This makes sense in terms of supporting high volume transactions.  I visited FDMS once and talked to them a bit about their architecture.  To maintain a > 1k TPS processing capability, they can't even wait for database writes when you're authorizing.  That authorization code you get back is assigned from a pre-determined pool.  The data about the transaction is pushed off to another process for persisting to a large back end system for later settlement.  This is why many of the non-gateways have rules about waiting x minutes before trying to settle; the data isn't in the settlement system for a bit after authorization.  This is also the reason why the authorization code expires after a while - they re-use it.  (Someone got the bright idea that they'd charge you extra for letting the auth code expire.....probably due to the increased load of data they need to store in the settlement system waiting for these things to time out.)

Checking a credit balance is also not part of a normal credit card processing workflow.  Mostly you attempt to authorize and get one of 3 results: a hard decline, a soft decline, or an authorization.  A balance check isn't really needed, and would probably open up some privacy or security issues if it were available.

Cash cards (like pre-loaded Visas) use a different administrative activiation and management API.  Gift cards work the same way, and you can use that administrative API to get balances.  This is a special case because these technically aren't credit cards.

I've not dealt much with the back end settlement networks that the issuing banks and the acquiring banks use to transfer data during settlement.  To get this kind of info, you'd have to have access to this network.  You might want to check the "any cash terminal will give you a balance" statement a bit.  It would make sense that you could get your balance from an issuing bank's ATM, but try to do it on one of those third-party type machines you find in gas stations that is not from your issuing bank to see if it works.  If you use a true credit card (not a debit card - that is a different network entirely), I don't know that it will show you your balance.

Comment: +1. The fact that this question has even been asked scares me half to death. The ATM networks are high-walled for very good/obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that I can think of is to use the AuthOnly method and try running (and voiding) multiple transactions, incrementing the PaymentAmount values until it fails.

Answer (score -2):

> > Is there ability to get in some way Balance on CreditCard ?

No.

> > API of Authorize.net or Paypal were examined on this subject and no results.

That's because you can't get someone else's balance. It's private information.

> > In real life any cash terminal can **show to you** balance on your credit card. That is why I assume there is some way to get this balance in web through some payment gateway.

Emphasis on the '**show to you**' part because you own the card. And the only allowed parties involved is the cardholder (with card in hand and pin) and the issuing bank and/or card company. Even over the phone there are security checks (Date of birth, zip/postal code, etc)

You will (should) never be able to get, through an API, gateway solution, or otherwise, the card holders balance unless you are affiliated with the issuing credit card and have been requested by the card holder after security checks.

This would be a gaping security and privacy hole. Think of all the professional credit card theifs being able to pull the balance amounts on thousands of credit cards in order to help know which cards and how much of an amount to charge, transfer and extort.

Comment: I would assume that the requests would be properly encrypted and dependent on authorization. The OP did not ask to do anything illegal.

Comment: I didn't mean the OP wanted to do anything illegal. I was pointing out how it could be used if it was allowed in order to stress why it is not possible. Payment gateways can only check if the amount to be charged will pass or not. The only way you can get the balance on a CC is with the card holders authorization which is not given on purchases. It requires a password to your bankaccount or client verification. For example look at www.mint.com : they are only able to get the balance on the accounts you give them because you authorized them by giving them your passwords to login on your behalf.

Comment: I am talking about you mentioning that it would make it easier for illegal activities to gather the exact amount and buy something for this exact amount. Just trying with 100$ until it doesn't work any more is much easier and by far less suspicious than trying to make a single payment with the full credit card limit. Those are blocked most of the times and the card gets frozen. So no use here for any illegal activities whatsoever.